# Keep fragment's state when changing tabs in bottom bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

Currently I have a `ViewPager` with 4 Tabs, each one is a different `Fragment`. I'm now switching my app to Bottom Bar Navigation but there's a problem with keeping the Fragment state and re-using it later.

The Problem :
Initially Tab_1 is visible. If user selects Tab_2 and then re-selects Tab_1, then I can see that the `Fragment` for Tab_1 goes through `onCreate()` and re-downloads the data from the server. With `ViewPager` I was using the `setOffScreenPagesLimit()` is there something equivalent with bottom bar ?

Comment: Did you find the solution?if yes then please shre